# Aggregate String[] grabbing first distinct, but I want it to grab the last distinct

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

I have a string like so
string dir ="video/video/About/video/video/"

When I run a split and run in through my linq statement it's grabbing the first distinct items, so video/About but I want it to grab the last possible distinct. so About/video

so "video/video/About/video/video/" should equal About/video

but "video/video/About/About" should still equal video/About

```
repeat = domain + dir.Split('/')
.Where(x => keep.Contains(x)).Distinct()
.Aggregate((gi, j) => gi + "/" + j) + repeat.Substring(lastSlash);
```

Comment: `string.Join("/", repeat.GroupBy(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.Count()).Select(x => x.Key))` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to `Reverse` it twice:

```
string result = domain + dir.Split('/')
        .Where(x => keep.Contains(x))
        .Reverse() //once before Distinct
        .Distinct()
        .Reverse() //and again afterwards
        .Aggregate((gi, j) => gi + "/" + j) + repeat.Substring(lastSlash);
```

So `video/video/About/video/video/` results to `About/video/`

and `video/video/About/About` results to `video/About/`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the overload of `Select` that takes in the index as part of the transformation (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx)).

If you want the last distinct element of each distinct element, you might try to use `GroupBy`  order each `IGrouping` accordingly, and grabbing the correct element of each group.

```
repeat = domain + dir.Split('/')
.Select((word, index) => Tuple.Create(word, index))
.Where(x => keep.Contains(x.Item1))
.GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Item2).First())
.OrderBy(x => x.Item2)
.Select(x => x.Item1)
.Aggregate((gi, j) => gi + "/" + j) + repeat.Substring(lastSlash);
```

Here, we couple each word with its index (using the `Select` overload mentioned above).  Then we filter down to the words of interest.  Instead of using `Distinct`, we now use `GroupBy` to generate an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Tuple<string, int>>`.  Since `IGrouping` itself implements `IEnumerable`, we project our list of `IGroupings` to a list of `Tuple<string, int>` by taking the last element of each `IGrouping` when ordered by index.  Then we order our new list of `Tuples` by the index so that the words remain in order, and project to the `string` part of the tuple.

Comment: Well I can't reverse the whole string, as something like video/video/about/about would appear as
about/video if it was reversed, I just want to grab the last distinct.

Comment: @Spooks I have updated the answer to suit the more complex version.